# How to change colors pixel by pixel with d3.js / SVG?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a svg element with a height and width of 800px and calculated every pixel's color of it stored in an two-dimension array color[800][800].
How can I change colors pixel by pixel with d3.js / SVG?
I think of one method: create 800*800 circles with a radius of 0.5px and assign the color[800][800] to their fill attributes. But it's too ugly, right? Is there any way more elegant?

Comment: The notion of recreating your "canvas" or outer element pixel-by-pixel can work OK. I would only suggest you create svg:rect elements instead of circles. Drawing circles for this case is an unnecesaryly more cpu intensive task

Comment: This sounds like something suited to canvas and not SVG at all.